# django-template assign url to a variable

Tags: django, django-templates

How can I assign an url to a variable into a template?
I've tried:

```
{% with url_news = url 'news'  %}
```

and

```
 {% with url 'news' as url_news %}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the `as` option of the [`url` tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#url)

```
{% url 'news' as the_url %}
{% if the_url %}
<a href="{{ the_url }}">Link to optional stuff</a>
{% endif %}
```

Note that when you use this syntax, it will fail silently if the url can't be resolved.

Comment: What about defining multiple urls?

Comment: @Clayton you can use the url tag multiple times, for example `{% url 'first_view' as first_url %}{% url 'second_view' as second_url %}`.